# loading in textures from json model THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I have made a model from a pool table where i added textures in the maya editor but when i load it into the javascript file it won't show the textures.

how do i get the textures to work

```
var scene, camera, renderer;
var controls, mesh;
init();
animate();

function init() {
scene = new THREE.Scene();
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
directionalLight.position.set( 0, 10, 0 );
scene.add( directionalLight );
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( "js/biljart.json", function ( geometry) {
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial() );
    mesh.position.x =0;
    mesh.position.y =-1;
    mesh.position.z =0;
    scene.add(mesh);
});

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(65, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
camera.position.z = 10;
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth - 20, window.innerHeight - 20);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
controls.addEventListener( 'change', animate );
}

function animate() {
renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

this is the js file

Comment: You are manually assigning a blank `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial` to the mesh. You should let the `JSONLoader()` assign the material. See the example in Three.JS documentation: https://threejs.org/docs/api/loaders/JSONLoader.html

Comment: i tried your solution and now it just chooses a random color instead of the texture jpg that has been assigned to the correct shapes, do you have any other solution?

Comment: Make sure the texture files are in the right place. Is your browsers loading them? Could you post a jsfiddle?